# Node JS + MySQL +ETIMEDOUT issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am getting below error from mysql while doing select query.

[Error: read ETIMEDOUT]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true }

I have active mysql connection.

THere is no problem in that.But I am getting below error. It is happening occasionally.So I am not able to figure out. Experts can help me out this.  There is enough number of maximum connection.

Comment: Still I have this issue.. it is happening occasionally. if I restart my node the problem getting resolved.